# How to check where the code redirect in a PHP and jquery project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a open source e-shop called Prestashop.

The problem is, when I disable a module, the site will auto refresh. I would like to know which part of the code and file caused the problem.

Here is the site:

```
prestigefood.com.hk/zh/
```

Are there any way to check through browser's developer console / tools to see:

1. Redirect caused by JS / PHP?
2. Where is that part of code

Comment: For 1) you could try disabling javascript and see if you get redirected.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. When you disable a module the site constantly refreshes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is caused by a JS function inside `/js/tools.js` :

```
function autoUrl(name, dest)
{
    var loc;
    var id_list;

    id_list = document.getElementById(name);
    loc = id_list.options[id_list.selectedIndex].value;
    if (loc != 0)
        location.href = dest+loc;
    return ;
}
```

Or

```
function autoUrlNoList(name, dest)
{
    var loc;

    loc = document.getElementById(name).checked;
    location.href = dest + (loc == true ? 1 : 0);
    return ;
}
```

It will be your work to find where it's called ;)

Comment: @user782104, a good way to make it clear what part of your code is redirecting you is to add a get var to the end of each redirect. For example, if your code originally calls location.href = 'page.php' in one place and then calls the same location.href = 'page.php' some where else, change them so you call location.href = 'page.php?method=1'; and location.href = 'page.php?method=2';, this way, when you are redirected, the address bar will clearly show you how you got there. This approach will work for your js or PHP code ;)

Comment: But the problem is that he doesn't know where the redirect code is...  And I don't understand where is the benefit of your method...

Comment: Like I said, if the OP adds the get var to each redirect in their code with a different value set for each, when the redirect occurs, the browser addres-bar will show the get var like `http://www.mysite/page.php?method=2` and the OP will immediately know which part of their code caused the redirect.from there, tracking down the issue is trivial

Comment: For example, when my users are timed out on my site due to inactivity, I log them out and redirect them to `http://somesite.com/login.php?tmdout=1`.  Alternatively, if a user attempts to access data they are not permitted to, I log them out and redirect them to `http://somesite.com/login.php?uaac=1`.    this way, while I'm testing, when a redirect occurs, I can look at the address bar and see EXACTLY which line of code caused the redirect and why. Additionally, you can use the get vars to display meaningful feedback to your users if needed

Comment: You didn't understood the problem. He wants to stop the redirection, which happens because he doesn't know where the redirection code is !

Comment: No, you did not understand my suggestion. You have pointed out at least 2 places in the OP's code (completely neglecting any serverside code that be the real culprit BTW) and you stated **It will be your work to find where it's called**. I expanded on that by advising the OP of a method that they could use to determine **which part of their code is calling the redirect**. I

Comment: As the redirect is done in JS, just a `Ctrl+f` into the code :)

Comment: You cannot possibly know for sure that the redirect in question is in fact called by either of those functions. They could be completely unrelated to the issue for all you know. the OP asked **"Are there any way to check through browser's developer console / tools to see : 1) Redirect caused by JS / PHP?"** Maybe the JS is the cause, maybe not, using the method I described, you will know for 100% certain exactly where the redirect is called in about 2 seconds......Im not sure what else to say here.... have a good day